# Where to ask questions on mathematics

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, math-se

I need to know where to ask questions on Calculus

Comment: My bad, ignore my original answer.  Mathoverflow is not for general math questions. See discussion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/mathoverflow-net-how-can-we-get-members-of-this-site-and-the-so-sf-su-sites-to-s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [David Speyer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141333/david-e-speyer) on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/mathoverflow-net-how-can-we-get-members-of-this-site-and-the-so-sf-su-sites-to/34595#34595) answer:

> If the question is an interesting but elementary puzzle: [The Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community)
> For standard high school or undergraduate material: [Dr. Math](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054714/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/)

More importantly, if the question falls into one of the above categories, *DON'T* go to mathoverflow.net.

Comment: I totally agree with the answer, but I would just like to throw out that Dr. Math is way too overworked (too many questions not enough doctors) to be a reliable source for new questions unless if your question has already been answered in the past.  Not mathoverflow's problem, but just wanted to weigh in.

Answer (score 6):

There is now [Mathematics - Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), which says in it's [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Mathematics - Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related
>   fields. We welcome questions about:
>
> - Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems
> - Hints on mathematical problems (but please read our [FAQ about homework questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question))
> - History and development of mathematics
> - Solving mathematical puzzles
> - Software that mathematicians use

(Read the full FAQ to see the limits.)

Comment: Paulo, if you're going to answers all of the older questions similar to this one, could you also point them to the more general link from the faq: [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions)

Comment: Ah, good idea, thanks. Not today, though. (If someone else wants to do this, simply look in the *Related questions* on the right. `==>`)

Answer (score 2):

In [MathOverflow's FAQ](https://mathoverflow.net/faq), several alternative sites are suggested:

> **MathOverflow is not for homework help.**  Try to make sure your
> question is of interest to at least
> one other **mathematician**. Though
> there are no hard and fast rules about
> who may post here, the intended
> audience is professional
> mathematicians, mathematics graduate
> students, and advanced undergraduates.
> If your question is closed as "off
> topic," it might be because it was too
> elementary. This doesn't mean that
> your question is "bad," just that
> MathOverflow isn't the right place for
> it. But there are lots of other math
> Q&A sites where your question might
> fit right in, like [Ask Dr. Math](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054714/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/),
> [Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/index.php), or
> [NRICH](http://nrich.maths.org/discus/messages/board-topics.html). If your question was
> closed as "too localized," it was
> probably an explicit homework problem
> (or looked like one). MathOverflow is
> not the right place for such
> questions; they send the message that
> you want somebody else to do your work
> for you, and you're not even willing
> to ask it in a general form. You may
> want to try asking such questions at
> [Tutorii](http://tutorii.com/).

This is just a selection. Of course, if you ask [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=ca&client=firefox-a&hs=saY&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&q=Where+to+ask+questions+on+mathematics%3F&btnG=Cerca&lr=&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=), it will you more options.