# Mathematics questions

Tags: support, scope, site-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to ask questions on mathematics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34453/where-to-ask-questions-on-mathematics)

I know the site mathoverflow.com and have posted questions. But unfortunately no one give me an answer if I post here. Can anybody help me? It is not homework.

Because I know somebody will say it is homework, asking "what you have tried?". But this is not so. I don't know how to solve. Please, if it is possible I will post here, OK?

Comment: As has been pointed out to you before, this is not a maths Q&A site.

Comment: SO is for programming-related questions. The above question is not accepted either. The above is a question about SO itself, and such questions should be posted at meta.

Comment: MO is for PhD-level maths, not high-school algebra :-)

Comment: Why was this migrated to Meta?

Answer (score 0):

Better keep the math staffs in the related site. This is only for direct programming problems.

Comment: And that had to be a comment not an answer...

Answer (score -2):

Don't ask if you may ask your question. Just post it and if it fits in SO topics it will be answered.

Comment: And that had to be a comment not an answer...